# Change tooltip size in yii2

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii2-advanced-app

i am using tooltip in yii2 `ActiveForm` on `field` and i could not figure that how to change the size and color of the tooltip

I can not figure out which css class i should override to achieve it

is it possible to change the size through `jquery` or any other way

Here is my `view` file
thank you

```
<script>
   $(function() {
       $( "[title]" ).tooltip();
   });
</script>

<div class="site-signup">
<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(  ['data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
            'data-placement' =>
                'right',
            'title' => 'Username should contain at least 6 characters'
        ]) ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput()->textInput( ['data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
            'data-placement' => 'right',
            'title' => 'Password should contain at least 6 characters'
        ]) ?>

          <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Signup', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
            </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override `bootstrap.css` with below code...

```
.tooltip-inner {
     max-width: 350px;
     /* If max-width does not work, try using width instead */
     width: 350px; 
}
```

Comment: `width` is working perfectly.. If i want to change the `background-color` or `font-color` i assume that i need to change in the same section right???